# Binary Search on Generic Array returning first two Index or Stackoverflow Exception

Tags: java, arrays, comparator, binary-search, generic-collections

Homework Question! We are using Binary Searches with Generic Arrays and Comparator. The assignment requires we have Integer / Double / String type arrays and that we can search each of them with a Binary Search. I have successfully used Binary Searching on non-Generic arrays before, this is a bit more difficult though. I generate my Arrays prior to calling the search, prompt user for selection, then perform the search (that's the idea). The currently implement Binary Search SORT of works. It will find the key on the first two index locations...throw a stackoverflow exception on mid range index, high end index return nothing, and input not found spits out -1 (I will add an output for that when the Binary Search works). I know the problem is falling in how I am implementing my Binary Search, I am just failing to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. Code is below:

```
  public static void searchIntegers() {
    System.out.print("Please enter the Integer you would like to search for: ");
    try {
        keyInt = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print(keyInt + " is found in index " + binarySearch(integerArray, keyInt));
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException inputMismatchException) {
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.printf("Please enter only Integers. Try again. \n\n");
    }  
}
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int binarySearch(E[] list, E key) {
    return binarySearch(list, key, 0, list.length);
}
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int binarySearch(E[] list, E key, int low, int high) {
    int mid = low + high / 2;

    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (list[mid].equals(key)) {
        return mid;
    }
    else if (list[mid].compareTo(key) == -1) {
        return binarySearch(list, key, mid +1, high);
    }
    else {
        return binarySearch(list, key, low, mid -1);
    }
}
    public static void generateArrays() {
    //GENERATE INTEGER ARRAY
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        integerArray[i] = generator.nextInt(100);
    }
    Arrays.sort(integerArray);
    //GENERATE DOUBLE ARRAY
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        doubleArray[i] = i + generator.nextDouble();
    }
    Arrays.sort(doubleArray);     
}
```

Comment: `list[mid].compareTo(key) == -1` The result of `compareTo()` is defined to be less than, equal to, or greater than zero. It might not be `-1`. I don't know if this is causing the specific problem you see, but if not, it's definitely a latent bug.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically failing at the check for low and high and going into an loop

Try this -

```
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int binarySearch(E[] list, E key, int low, int high) {


    int mid = (low + high) / 2;

    if (low > high) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (list[mid].equals(key)) {
        return mid;
    } else if (list[mid].compareTo(key) == -1) {
        return binarySearch(list, key, mid + 1, high);
    } else {
        return binarySearch(list, key, low, mid - 1);
    }
}
```

You need to add brackets to your mid calculation.
Just a suggestion, check for overflow conditions as well.

Comment: It looks exactly the same as mine? I don't understand what I am missing. The overflow was coming from line 119, which was my

            else {
            return binarySearch(list, key, low, mid -1);
        }

I transposed your code into mine and it functions 100%, I am going to comb through the side-by-side to look for differences. I am not saying it isn't there, I am just not seeing it, probably because I have been staring at this for a while now. Thank you!

Comment: Check the first if-else condition and mainly, the change is this -
int mid = (low + high) / 2